# Parsing lines with read() system call C Linux

Tags: c, linux, file, operating-system, system

I am trying to to take a file in C and read through it with the read() system call. I want to parse the file into individual lines and perform some string manipulation on these lines before writing them out to another file.

I am not sure on how to parse file lines into just using read(). I know I can use fgets but I need to only use read(). I know I can get the count of lines using read like this:

```
size_t lines = 0;
char c;
while (read(in_fd, &c, 1) == 1) {
    if (c == '\n') {
        lines++;
    }
}

printf("Linecount: %zu\n", lines);
```

I want to get the lines in string format though, so then I can use a for loop to loop through the lines and perform a manipulation on each line.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Would it help if you knew how to append a character onto a string?

Comment: A more efficient approach would be to over-read into a buffer. If you didn't get a line feed, expand the buffer and read some more. If you did, copy the string into a new buffer and remove what you've read from the buffer. That's what `fgets` does. The downside is that all the reads from that handle need to use that buffer.

Comment: If you want to read a byte at a time, you still want to start with an oversized buffer. Allocate an area that should be large enough (using `malloc`). Read a byte at a time into the buffer, until you encounter a line feed or EOF, or run out of space. In the latter case, expand the buffer (using `realloc`) and continue. Once you're done, free up the unused space (using `realloc`).